# Reflecting the response obtained from service on cells of other viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a Singleton class in which I have requested a service using NSURLSession .In response the service returns a dictionary Books. In Books dictionary there are values for keys writer, price, name .I want to show these values on cells of table view on other ViewController B.I am new to ios development and have checked a number of links for NSUrlsession but still couldn't solve the real purpose. Kindly help with some example in objective-C. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Plz read the uitableview tutorial first.

Comment: I know table view cells .....m just not able to understand that how data from singleton class will be passed to the cells .....I have tried doing it through properties but the couldn't reach to the output

Comment: can you show your dictionary values?

Answer (score 0):

Create a method inside the singleton class that has a block. Call this method from your viewcontroller wherever you wanna display the data.

Put the data fetch inside this method and call the block on successfully fetching the data. Reload the cells in your viewController inside the block
Something like this-

In your singleton object-

```
-(void)fetchDataAndOnCompletion:(void(^)(NSDictionary *dict, NSError *error))completion;
```

Call the above method from inside your viewController and inside the completion block `[tableView reloadData];`

Edit: Make sure you set the array you are using to populate the tableView with the response before calling reload.